# Creating a New Directory and Writing a File in it

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, directory

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(precombine); // I am creating a new directory.

BinaryWriter write = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(di.FullName, FileMode.Create));   // I want to open a file in it

write.Write(buffer);   // and then I want to write in it.
```

However, I get an error of not to have any permission to write in it. How can I create a new directory for a user and then write the data of the user in it ? Thanks.

Comment: If you have the choice of where to create the directory then chose a directory where the user will have write privilege - like the Users documents folder for example.

Comment: It creates the directory no problem, but after that it can not write into the newly created directory.However if i use an already existing directory not create a new one, then it writes the data.

Comment: @CemAytekin Note: If you have an error, *always* post the exact error itself, don't only describe the error or say whats in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be missing the filename - "di.FullName" will give the full pathname of the directory you have created - File.Open needs a file name.

```
BinaryWriter write = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(di.FullName, <FILE NAME HERE>), FileMode.Create));
```

In your code, File.Open will be attempting to create a file with the same name as the directory you have just created - so you don't have permission.

Comment: so how can I fix this ?

Comment: The code above shows you how to fix the problem - you need to append the file name to the directory name.

Comment: when I put an existing path into File.Open, it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried appending the filename as I have suggested?

Comment: Yes you are right ! Now it works thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble writing authority "run as Administrator "

```
string rootPath = @"C:\FileSystem\";
string fileName = "data.txt";
if (!Directory.Exists(rootPath))
Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath);

File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(rootPath , fileName), "Test");
File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(rootPath , fileName), "Test2");
```

For a bottom row  > Environment.NewLine > \n

```
File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(rootPath , fileName), "Test2"+Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: I tried, it still says "Acces to the path is denied"

Comment: I think that should be _"Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName)"_

Comment: @CemAytekin: where are you trying to create the directory?

Comment: @CemAytekin : Would you try it on another directory except C?